# How to find the particular integral of an ODE with an inhomogeneous component formed from the sum of exponentials and powers of trig?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-3y'+2y=e^{2x}+\cos^2x$$

What trial solution is recommended? The standard trial solution would be (unless I'm mistaken):

$$y=ke^{2x}+(a\sin x+b\cos x)(p\sin x+q\cos x)$$

However, the values of $k, a, b, p$ and $q$ would take forever to work out by hand, so there must be an easier method, but I am at a loss on what to do.

I would appreciate any alternative methods for finding the particular integral in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method is to split the RHS as
$$
e^{2x}+\cos^2x=e^{2x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)
$$
and look for a particular integral as the sum
$$
y_1(x)+y_2(x)+y_3(x)
$$
where $y_k$ are particular integrals for each term as RHS separately, i.e. $y_1''-3y_1'+2y_1=e^{2x}$ etc

P.S. Since $e^{2x}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, it is not possible to find $y_1$ as $k
e^{2x}$, one would need $k(x)e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the complementary function is of the form $$Ae^x+Be^{2x}$$ this is a "failure case", so you can't use $\lambda e^{2x}$ as part of the particular integral.

The PI to use is $$\lambda xe^{2x}+\mu+\alpha\cos2x+\beta\sin2x$$